# Как в алгоритме переводящем текст из английской раскладки в русскую определить, какой текст нужно так обрабатывать, а какой нет?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код :

```
while True:
    vvod=input()
    raskladka = dict(zip(map(ord,


                            "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,.&"
                            'QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:"ZXCVBNM<>&'),
                            "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю?"
                            'ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ?'

                               ))

                       
    print(vvod.translate(raskladka))
```

Как дать ему понять, что нужно переводить в английскую раскладку, а что нет, дабы случайно не перевести стандартный английский?

Comment: посчитать статистику букв, биграмм.

Comment: Ну, задача не тривиальная. Словари, либо статистика. Смотреть, если после трансляции слово не попадает в словари или статистика не стала лучше, чем была (с бОльшей вероятностью даёт принадлежность какому-то языку), то значит переводить не надо было.